# Setting the Colour a Programmatically Drawn View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, uikeyboard, cgrect

I'm in the middle of fixing my UITextView to not show underneath the keyboard, but instead to resize it to the correct constraints. This is probably a stupid question and there is most likely an easy fix alongside this stupid question, but I need to colour the view, that is currently black, to a `whiteColor` - and it seems that I'm blanking on the correct line of code to do so. I have searched Stack Overflow and Google for sometime but I have not found a single line of code that doesn't return error(s).

The black rectangle behind the keyboard.
[image: Screenshot]

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGRect kbRect = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    kbRect = [[self view] convertRect:kbRect fromView:nil];
    CGSize kbSize = kbRect.size;
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;

    /* This should work, but doesn't quite qet the job done */
    //    UIEdgeInsets insets = self.textView.contentInset;
    //    insets.bottom = kbSize.height;
    //    self.textView.contentInset = insets;
    //
    //    insets = self.textView.scrollIndicatorInsets;
    //    insets.bottom = kbSize.height;
    //    self.textView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets;

    /* Instead, we just adjust the frame of the uitextview */
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height + VERTICAL_KEYRBOARD_MARGIN;
    self.companyTextField.frame = aRect;

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your application might not need or want this behavior.
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, self.companyTextField.frame.origin) ) {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, self.companyTextField.frame.origin.y - kbSize.height);
        [self.companyTextField setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Set the background color of the container view to white. (the main window view) and also the scrollview background color to white. Or if you have another view behind it set it to white. By looking at the image it seems you are actually resizing the view, not the textview.

Comment: usually self.view color is black and you are using scrollview.As we are not very clear about which which view is in black color. Set color for self.view to red and scrollview to blue. and check so that we can easily know which view has black background color so that we can fix easily

Comment: @CharanGiri Settings the background colour of `self.view` seemed to do what was expected, however I do not understand how I would set the background colour of the `scrollview`. [SelfViewRedScreenshot.png](http://i.imgur.com/wHnuLmH.png?1)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `self.companyTextField` is what you're talking about:

```
self.companyTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

If you're talking about the main view:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Comment: hes talking about the view behind it since textview is being resized.

Comment: Yes, what @Chiquis is referring to is what I'm trying to colour. Unfortunately neither your original, nor your edit seem to work. :(

Comment: @MattBush I think thats because you have a scrollview with a black background.

Comment: @Chiquis how would I go about setting the colour of that scrollview in my code?

Comment: Could you provide more information on the views that are contained in your controller? From the screenshot I can see a UIToolbar and a UITextView. Are there any other views between those 2 and the view of your controller?

Answer (score 1):

Set the background color of the container view to white. (the main window view) and also the scrollview background color to white.

Or if you have another view behind it set it to white.

Edit: Your code shows a scrollview, check its color.

Comment: Yes, I've tried setting the background colour: `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];`, I've also set every property to that of `whiteColor`.

Comment: I might have been mistaken, you don't seem to have a scroll view but instead you scroll the contents of the text field? its a bit strange, usually you have a big scroll view covering the screen, and you set the content offset of this scroll view to move the whole text view up. Your commented code says so aswell "// If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible"